# How can I create a google scholar profile without publicaitons?

Tags: publications, google-scholar

I'm currently doing my master's in physics. I have written a few articles which are yet to be communicated. But I'm graduating within 3 months due to which I will lose my institute email ID. And since the creation of a profile on google scholar mandates an institution ID as well as articles, Im at a loss. I have done a minor project due to which I have a minor thesis document at hand and I have seen scholar profiles where the first publication kept on it is not published in any journal but instead was a thesis report. Is there anyway I could use my minor thesis to open a google scholar profile? It would be nice if I could know where to upload my thesis so that it would be searchable on google scholar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The google scholar help page says that you can change your institutional id. So set it up now and change it later. I think google scholar searches arXiv; if so posting your thesis there will work.